# Is it legal to derive from std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, initializer-list

Can I use `std::initializer_list` list as a base class?

```
template <typename T>
struct il : std::initializer_list<T>
{
    using base = std::initializer_list<T>;

    il(base list): base(list) {}

    const T &operator[](size_t i) const
        { return *(base::begin()+i); }
};

void print2(il<int> list)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2)
        { std::cerr << list[i] << "; "; }

    std::cerr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    print2({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6});
}

// The output: 0; 2; 4; 6;
```

The code above works in both [GCC](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdc8ae2146baab1b) and [Clang](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7c92c302f967ac4). But is it actually valid?

The [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) defines `std::initializer_list` as follows:

```
template< class T >
class initializer_list;
```

But does this mean that `std::initializer_list` is an ordinary class like any other? I thought it is kind of special object in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The best reference to this I can find in the standard is [§16.4.5.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/constraints)

> The following subclauses specify constraints on ... [the program's] use of standard library classes as base classes

And then [later](https://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#derived.classes) in §16.4.5.5

> Virtual member function signatures defined for a base class in the C++ standard library may be overridden in a derived class defined in the program

Which would seem to imply that it's fair game to subclass stdlib classes.

Of course, *using* those subclasses as an actual `std::initializer_list` is going to be difficult. Every use case I can think of in C++ for `std::initializer_list` takes one by value, so your subclass is going to [get sliced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) before it ever gets passed to most constructors.